# Sequelize How compare year of a date in query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, datetime, sequelize.js

I'm trying to make this query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA AS A WHERE YEAR(A.dateField)='2016'
```

How can I perfome this query above in sequelize style?

```
TABLEA.findAll({
      where:{}//????
     }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
TABLEA.findAll({
  where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('YEAR', sequelize.col('dateField')), 2016)
 });
```

You have to use `.where` here, because the lefthand side of the expression (the key) is an object, so it cannot be used in the regular POJO style as an object key.

If you want to combine it with other conditions you could do:

```
TABLEA.findAll({
  where: {
    $and: [
      sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('YEAR', sequelize.col('dateField')), 2016),
      { foo: 'bar' }
    ]
  }
 });
```

https://sequelize.org/v3/docs/querying/#operators

Answer (score 4):

you have to add the `date_part` function to your query:

```
sequelize.where(sequelize.fn("date_part",'year',sequelize.col('dateField')), 2020)
```

Comment: The solution for multiple where clauses is incorrect, the and operator doesn't take an array. Se my suggestion since the edit to improve this solution was rejected.

Answer (score -1):

```
TABLE.findAll({
  where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('YEAR', sequelize.col('dateField')), 2016)
 });
```

You have to use .where here, because the lefthand side of the expression (the key) is an object, so it cannot be used in the regular POJO style as an object key.

If you want to combine it with other conditions you could do:

```
var Sequelize require('sequelize')
var Op = Sequelize.Op


TABLE.findAll({
  where: {
     foo: 'bar',
     [Op.and]:sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('YEAR', sequelize.col('dateField')), 2016)   
  }
 });
```

https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/querying.html#operators

Comment: 'andOp' isn't recognize, since it's a javascript object, and not a variable