# how to convert raw postgres query to select current year based on created date column to sequelize query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have this query:

> select * from table where date_part('year', created_at) = date_part('year', current_date)

but i am not sure how could i convert this into sequelize format.

I tried:

> [seqlib.fn("date_part", 'year', current_date, seqlib.col('table.created_at')), 'year'],

but it does not work

Comment: Hi date_part() is a function ?

Comment: take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38861087/sequelize-how-compare-year-of-a-date-in-query